# Determine the scrolling container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Assuming the scrolling container is the window, this JQuery code will put an element "foo" at the top of the window:

```
$(window).scrollTop($("#foo").offset().top)
```

But in these days of overcomplicated web pages composed from myriad sources and generated markup, the scrolling container is far from guaranteed to be the window. It could be a `div` or anything else that supports scrollbars and child elements.

Is there a straightforward, browser independent way to determine the scrolling container?

Should I look for the nearest container that specifies overflow?

HTML5 is fine.

Comment: "scrolling container is far from guaranteed to be the window", would you like to explain the problem more; like adding the exact case where you are not able to determine the scrolling container?